# Using Ninja as a generator with MSYS2 + MinGW on Windows 10 x64

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mingw, ninja

I am using MSYS2 + MinGW x64 + CMake as my development setup on windows. Currently, to initialize my projects, I open a *"MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit"* shell and invoke CMake as follows:

```
cmake .. -G"MinGW Makefiles"
```

This works nicely, but I'd like to use `ninja` instead of `make`. Therefore, I installed [`mingw-w64-x86_64-ninja`](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-ninja?repo=mingw64) via my MSYS2 shell, making it available in my MinGW environment. I expected

```
cmake .. -G"Ninja"
```

to work, but instead it fails with the following errors:

> ```
> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
> -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
> -- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
> -- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - broken
> CMake Error at C:/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
>   The C compiler
>
>     "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"
>
>   is not able to compile a simple test program.
>
>   It fails with the following output:
>
>     Change Dir: C:/projecct/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
>     Run Build Command(s):C:/msys64/usr/bin/ninja.exe cmTC_c3f3d && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_c3f3d.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
>     FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_c3f3d.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
>     C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_c3f3d.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -c testCCompiler.c
>     /bin/sh: line 1: C:msys64mingw64bingcc.exe: command not found
>     ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
>
>
>
>
>
>   CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
>
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
> See also "C:/project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
> See also "C:/project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
> ```

Judging from the following line

```
 /bin/sh: line 1: C:msys64mingw64bingcc.exe: command not found
```

it seems that this is a `/` vs `\` issue.

- **Is there a solution or workaround to this problem?**
- **Can I use Ninja as my generator on a MSYS2 + MinGW x64 setup on Windows 10?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my company we use mingw64 + ninja on windows 10 on a daily basis. I am not sure what is going wrong in your setup, here's a few tips:

- Run cmake from the *mingw64* shell, not the *msys2* shell (usually `C:/msys64/mingw64.exe`)
- Make sure you installed `mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake`, not just `cmake` or `mingw-w64-cmake`.
- Make sure you installed `mingw-w64-x86_64-ninja`, not just `ninja` or `mingw-w64-ninja`.

With these 2 items in mind, on my windows 10 machine I can configure and compile with ninja successfully (granted our setup is a bit old, we froze a msys2 version from a couple of years ago).

Comment: I am following both of your points. I am using the `mingw64` shell for compilation, and `msys2` shell only to install packages. I have installed `mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake` -- the `which cmake` command reports `/mingw64/bin/cmake`.

Comment: mmm... I have seen this problem before on a colleague's laptop, but I can't remember how we fixed it. Will take better look tomorrow

Comment: I feel like a dumbass. I accidentally installed `mingw-w64-ninja` instead of `mingw-w64-x86_64-ninja`. I was so sure I double-checked that...

Comment: I don't  know what a `mingw-w64-xxx` package is. Do you mean `-i686`?

Comment: no, you can download and install [these](https://packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-cmake) via a MSYS2 shell.

Answer (score 2):

same problem

```
pacman -R ninja
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-ninja
```

resolved - wrong ninja!